# Is it possible to redirect output of one program to input of other program in different operating systems?

Tags: redirect, operating-system

It is possible to redirect the output of one program to the input of another program within Unix operating systems.

```
cat *.txt | sort | uniq > result-file
```

Is it possible to do this with other operating systems (like Windows)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common operating systems have notions of standard input, standard output and pipes. The command-line syntax, however, depends on the shell you are using.

You can get Bash for Windows with [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/).

You can also use pipes on Windows with plain old CMD.exe. The syntax is very similar, using `>` to write to files, `>>` to append, `<` to read from files and `|` for piping between processes. You can read more about it here: http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html

If you are the adventurous type that uses PowerShell, then you can read about piping between programs here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176927.aspx