# Apply multiple filters for same files in git

Tags: git, version-control, filter, gitattributes

I am using Git for version control of local files, which finally have to be checked in into another version control system. Now I am experiencing some problems with most of the C code files:

1. They all have an automatic version history in their header comment
2. Most of the files are cluttered by EasyCode or EasyCase comments

I now simply created two git filters "History" and "EasyTool" to clean up the code before being checked in to Git. How is it possible to filter all C and H files with both of the filters?

Specifying the commands multiple times does not work and concatenation of the filter command does neither (or I at least did not find the correct syntax).

This was my first try:

```
*.c  filter=History
*.c  filter=EasyTool           # This one wins, "History" is not executed
```

Then I tried something like this:

```
*.c  filter=History EasyTool   # The first wins, other separators work neither
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can chain filters that way.

The simplest way would be to write a wrapper which would call both sequentially (at least through a pipe in a shell script).
(as in "[Is it possible to redirect output of one program to input of other program in different operational systems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047280/is-it-possible-to-redirect-output-of-one-program-to-input-of-other-program-in-di)").