# How would I protect a certain file from being processed by a git filter?

Tags: git, gitattributes, git-filter

Say I've got that git filter that does some cleanup on the XML files used in my project. Configuration is done like this:

```
*.xml filter=clear-xml
```

One thing that filter does in the `clean` step is to check whether there's an empty line at the end of the file and if not, it adds one. The `smudge` part of the filter does nothing.

Now, there's this single unique XML file that gets generated without an empty line at the end. This file shall not be processed by the `clear-xml` filter.

How would I approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As illustrated in "[Apply multiple filters for same files in git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13988619/6309)", you cannot chain multiple filters: the last one apply.

That means you could declare a second "[noop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP)" filter (one which does nothing) specifically for your file.

```
*.xml filter=clear-xml
yourFile.xml filter=noop
```

Comment: what a lucky break that I have a special filter processing this file anyways. Just swapped the sequence in the `.gitattributes` and it works. Thanks!

Comment: @eckes great! This confirms how filters are processed (I didn't see that processing order explicitly documented in http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#__code_filter_code)